# BitmapImage Rotation

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, bitmapimage

In my ModelView I have an ObservableCollection of BitmapImages that displays in a listbox on my view. I am trying to rotate the selected image in the ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out and you can let me know if something looks stupid

```
//Create a transform
TransformedBitmap tBmp = new TransformedBitmap();
tBmp.BeginInit();

//Set the source = to the image currently selected
tBmp.Source = _Scans[_selectedImage].MyImage;
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform(180);
tBmp.Transform = rt;
tBmp.EndInit();

//Create a new source after the transform
BitmapSource s1 = tBmp;
BitmapImage bi = BitmapSourceToBitmapImage(s1);

//Add create the item and replace the current item in the collection
//edited according to comment
//ScannedImages s = new ScannedImages();
//s.MyImage = bi;
//_Scans[_selectedImage] = s;
Scans[_selectedImage].MyImage = BitmapSourceToBitmapImage(s1);
```

Comment: Ok, scratch the last part where I make a new item and add it to the collection. I am fairly new to WPF and databinding and forgot to put the NotifyPropertyChanged on the items within the collection. SO the last 4 lines of code should be this line. Scans[_selectedImage].MyImage = BitmapSourceToBitmapImage(s1);

Answer (score 0):

In your DateTemplate where you define how you would like to display your Image (as ListBox Item), you can use `.RenderTransform` property to transform/rotate your Control.

Example for Button:

```
<Button
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="45"/>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
            Test</Button>
```

[Have a read more on How to Rotate an object? MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754009.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to do this directly in the Observable Collection in the modelView as I don't want to rotate all of the images, just the one that is selected?

Comment: you dont have to rotate all images, use DataTemplate with your Listbox and it will rotate them for you. otherwise you have to manipulate your image outside WPF and add it to collection in "rotated state"

Comment: Thats what I want since if the image gets rotated I need to save it back out the same way in an XPS file. I also only had 1 rotate button, I didn't put it in the Listbox.

Comment: if you haven't used DataTemplate, then you can use Style to your Image so that all of them rotates on initialize. haven't worked much with XPS, not sure how print/save process works